# Razor pages Runtime compilation accessing internal class of a class library

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I'm trying to use Runtime compilation with asp.net core Razor pages.

I'm using an Internal class inside another Class library
using **InternalsVisibleTo** to allow my project to access the internal class.
this used to work fine with other projects and asp.net.

but razor runtimecompilation can't access the class

I've already tried to add these:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting")]

[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Page")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageLoader")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures")]

[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("System")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("System.Runtime")]
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("System.Runtime.CompilerServices")]
```

I get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
***\Pages\Index.cshtml(17,30): error CS0122: 'Localizations' is inaccessible due to its protection level
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(String normalizedPath)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageLoader.LoadAsyncCore(PageActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, EndpointMetadataCollection endpointMetadata)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageLoaderMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsyncAwaited(CandidateSet candidates, Task`1 actionDescriptorTask, Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

A workaround is to make a local method that just calls the internal class's method.

back in asp.net webforms, adding the following namespace was sufficient:
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("ASP")]

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 6.0.1
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
ASP.Net core, .NET 6.0
```

Comment: Hi @Amro, are you sure your razor pages project can run successfully to invoke Index.cshtml?

Comment: @Rena, Yes it's working fine.